# California won't reissue stimulus check

Tags: check, california, stimulus

A family member, a resident of California, received a Golden State Stimulus check in 2021. There was a problem and he wrote "Void" on the check.

As per the instructions on the state website, he wrote to the state and requested the check be reissued. There was no response.

In 2022 he wrote a follow up letter. There was no response.

This week, he called the Franchise Tax Board. He was told that since the stimulus program has ended, it was too late to have the check reissued.

Is that actually true?

Even if it is, it's not like he waited too late for this reissue; he asked shortly after receiving the check. It's not his fault that they never responded.

Does he have no recourse?

Comment: What was the problem? Why did he write "void"? I found no instructions that would say that.

Comment: He deposited the check into his account through a phone app, then wrote "Void" on the check. But the deposit did not go through.  (I found that many people in the past have had the same thing happen with this institution's phone app.)

Comment: Has he tried this? https://www.sco.ca.gov/upd_msg.html

Comment: if he deposited the cheque shouldn't he ask his bank why the money is not in his account?

Comment: @user253751 They told us why; some kind of technical glitch. It just didn't go through. The problem is, they told him to write "Void" on the check *before* scanning it. (If I'd known this might happen, I would have had him write it on a piece of Scotch tape and affix it to the check)

Comment: @littleadv Yes, he did.  I checked it again now, just in case.

Comment: This is definitely weird. No bank should tell you to void the check *before* depositing it. It makes no sense. I don't know if there's any way to recover the funds at this point since the problem is not the fault of the FTB. If it doesn't show up at unclaimed funds directory then I'm guessing he's SOL.